# Select query according to date

Tags: sql, select

We have a table to store the Events.

Table has got a schema like

```
EventID INT Primary Key
EventName NVARCHAR(100)
StartDate Datetime
EndDate Datetime
```

So in the front end we want to show the events according to start time and end time.
From front end we are passing StartDate and EndDate as parameters to take the value.

So far we have taken like

```
   Select * from tbl_Events
   where ((startDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR (EndDate BETWEEN @start AND @end))
```

We have got 2 views to show the events -

1. A **month view** - which show all events in the month
2. A **day view** showing events of that day

Suppose i got an event with StartDate as 23 October 2012 and EndDate as 27 October 2012.

And i am passing `@StartDate as 24 Oct 2012` and `@EndDate as 25 OCt 2012`

According to the above query its working in the **Month view**. But its not working in the **day view**.

Can anyone please help me on this to modify the query

Comment: Try to use **language independent** formats for your date - i.e. the **ISO-8601** format in SQL Server - `YYYYMMDD`. So try to use `@StartDate = '20121024'` and `@EndDate = '20121027'`. Also - if you use `DateTime` as end date, then you need to use `'2012-10-27T23:59:59.997'` as your "end date" - otherwise you won't get any events that are scheduled some time during the day on Oct 27th.

Comment: or more correctly `... < date(@datetime) + 1day`.

Comment: @marc_s : k..yes i am saving time along with that.. i think its not related with time format , if i am passing '@StartDate as 20121024' and '@EndDate as 20121025', then also this query will not return anything..

Comment: @marc_s : k.. then also it will not work i think, since when i am comparing using the between 23 OCt is not between 24 and 25 th oct and also 27 Oct is not btween 24 and 25th OCt.. So it will not return any results

Comment: i dnt know why a minus vote for this question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overlapping logic should really be:

```
Select *
from tbl_Events
where startDate <= @end AND @start <= EndDate
```

Comment: It's not. Because the original does not allow BOTH table columns to be outside the range.